# Implementing counter refs

Tags: java, design-patterns, concurrency, hashmap

I want to implement a kind of counter approach.
The solution for now is something like:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> listeners = new HashMap<>();  

public void increaseListener(int id) {  
    synchronized(listeners) {  
       if(listeners.containsKey(id)) {  
          listeners.put(id, listeners.get(id) + 1);  
       }  
       else {  
          listeners.put(id, 1);  
       }  
    }  
}  

public void decreaseListener(int id) {  
   synchronized(listeners) {   
   if(listeners.containsKey(id)) {  
      return;
   } 
   listeners.put(id, listeners.get(id) - 1);  
   if(listeners.get(id) == 0) {  
     // no more listeners do something 
   }   
  }  
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? E.g. replacing hashmap with some other constructs or instead of integers have atomic references or some other way?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) which takes care of thread-safety for us. In particular, we can use its atomicity guarantees as follows:

```
final Map<Integer, Integer> listeners = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

void increaseListeners(final int id) {
  listeners.merge(id, 1, Integer::sum);
}

void decreaseListeners(final int id) {
  listeners.computeIfPresent(id, ($, count) -> {
    if (count == 1) {
      /* no more listeners -- do something ? */
    }
    return count - 1;
  });
}
```

A working demonstration of the above implementation is available [here on Ideone](http://ideone.com/PocgOQ).

Comment: Interesting convention, to use `$` for a throwaway lambda parameter. Is this your own invention?

Comment: @shmosel well `_` is still reserved so it seemed pretty natural; I think I've seen it before but I can't be certain

Answer (score 0):

Guava offers [`AtomicLongMap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html) which is meant for just this sort of case:

```
AtomicLongMap<Integer> listeners = AtomicLongMap.create();

public void increaseListener(int id) {
    listeners.incrementAndGet(id);
}

public void decreaseListener(int id) {
    if (listeners.decrementAndGet(id) == 0) {
        // no more listeners
    }
}
```

Comment: the only problem here is that the original `decreaseListener` places the count-is-zero logic within the `synchronized` block which a conditional branch on `decrementAndGet(id) == 0` does not adequately emulate

Comment: @oldrinb Valid observation, but I'm not convinced that the counting and the zero logic need to be mutually exclusive. If anything, the zero logic might need to be mutually exclusive with itself, in which case it can mind its own synchronization separately.

Comment: fair--I can't imagine a good reason why concurrent access to the map after calling `decrementAndGet` yet before the conditional zero logic would pose a problem here but I figured I'd choose an alternative as semantically similar to the original as possible to be safe